# Setting the background on a selected listview?

Tags: android, listview, background

I have the following 2 layout files to display a list of contact groups.  The view in it's normal state looks perfect.  Semi transparent list items over my background.  When I touch the list to move it the background goes to black rather than staying semi transparent.

gouplist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/megaphone_320x480">
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/android:list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@id/android:empty" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="No Groups" 
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

two_line_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_topText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#BBBBBB" 
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" 
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lv_bottomText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#BBBBBB" 
        android:background="#99000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cacheColorHint property needs to be set on the actual listview, like so. As 3dmg stated, it'll usually be set to the same background color as the container that the ListView is in. In the example below, the ListView would be inside a LinearLayout which also has a white (#FFF) background.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:cacheColorHint="#FFF" />
```

Comment: The color hint actually had to be set to #00 (transparent) then I just used 000000 to be consistent with my other background setting.  So android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" was what I used.  Now I can see my background through the list while it's selected and/or scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was this list parameter:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@color/colorOfYourList"
```

[android:cacheColorHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3acacheColorHint)

Comment: it will set color on entire listview .

Comment: This changed nothing for the selected list.  It's still going to black even though I set it to "#99000000".  The unselected list still looks perfect.

Comment: try setting `android:cacheColorHint="@color/#00000000"` instead

Comment: Where would this line go as it seems to not make any difference no matter where I put it.